# how to write output of cut to file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have custom generator on bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
while :
do
    echo "1 2 3 4"
    sleep 1
done
```

I want not **cut** 3rd column:

```
$ ./loop.sh | cut -d' ' -f3
```

This works fine, but when I try to output this to file:

```
$ ./loop.sh | cut -d' ' -f3 > myfile
```

nothing happen, this file is empty. I expected to see column of **3**'s, but got nothing. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It endless cycle. How do you exit from it?

Comment: @MichaelKazarian, I'm using cut to parse logs from web server(tail -f <log>), this is why I use endless loop.

Comment: How long did you wait to see whether something was written to `myfile`? It is probably buffering, and with 2 characters per second, it will take some time to flush the buffer.

Comment: @Evert, I wait couple of seconds. cut writes strings in 'realtime' manner, how can I turn off buffering?

Comment: A few seconds is definitely too short.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is probably buffering, as I mentioned in my comment. I get the same result when I try this.
You can use `stdbuf` to modify the buffering, like thus (at least, this works for me):

```
./loop.sh | stdbuf -o0 cut -d' ' -f3  > myfile
```

The buffering is done (or appears to be done) at the last part of the pipe chain, so that's where `stdbuf` is put.

See `man stdbuf` for the details.

Answer (score 4):

you get an empty file, because, the stdout is buffered.

If you want to prove it, you could try:

```
yes "test" > file
```

you have to do the same, `ctrl-c` to stop it, and there are alot of "test" in file.

with your script, if you remove the `sleep 1`, you will see  many `3` in your `myfile` too. with the `sleep`, I think you just pressed `ctrl-c` so fast that stdout buffer wasn't fulled/flushed.

If you want to skip the buffer, you could:

```
./loop.sh|stdbuf -o0 cut -d' ' -f3>myfile
```